# One war with multiple GWT apps

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, gwt

Is it possible to have multiple GWT apps (each with it's own html page) in one WAR archive?

I would like to have simple welcome page (handled by Spring MVC for example) from which the user can navigate to URLs of various independent GWT webapps. All in one war package.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes you can create it. You have to define different html and gwt.xml file one for each page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

Define one GWT module (.gwt.xml) file per independent GWT web app and one (or more) corresponding html file loading each GWT module javascript.

You navigate from app to app by *redirecting* to the corresponding html page.